# Subversion SVN fails randomly: Could not parse respond status line

Tags: svn

Sometimes when I try to commit with the Tortoise SVN Client I get the error:

```
 Could not parse respond status line
```

If I try again it sometimes fails again or works. It really bothers me!

Has anybody any suggestions what might cause it?

Answer (score 2):

if it sometimes fails, then its likely to be a network problem - you're likely not getting anything back at all. The second possibility is that the server is still processing/died/etc. I used to see similar on a small VM server when I committed a very large amount of data, the server couldn't keep up (especially with the virus checker taking up 99% of the CPU!)

If it works perfectly with small amounts of data, then I'd look at your server loading whilst you commit, otherwise I'd make sure your network is communicating perfectly.

Comment: It doesnt seem like it is the CPU, but I guess it is a Network Problem like you described.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a recent verison of TortoiseSVN, specifially one that's been released *since* the version of SVN on the repository server?